# How can I use buttons in my HTML to change the class name of the <html> element?

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML, my browser is IE9 and above and we are not using jQuery:

```
<html class="darkBlue">
```

What I would like to do is to be able to switch the class between the colors "darkBlue", "black" and "red" with the three button in my HTML (below) and have my application remember the last setting when a user visits the page next time.

I set up the following in my HTML:

```
<button>Blue</button>
<button>Black</button>
<button>Red</button>
```

How can I easily make the switch? I was thinking of two things:

- Having a very small script in the  that I could call in the click event.
- Coding everything in the click event of the buttons?

What I learned so far is that I will need to do a select of the `<html>` like this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector("html");
```

It was also suggested to me that I could use localstorage to store the last choice of color. Some advice would be much appreciated?

Comment: Do you have jQuery at your disposal?

Comment: We're not using jQuery.

Comment: Interesting. `html` tag also can have `class`. What do you do with that?

Comment: first of all you shouldn't use a class on the html tag, but rather have  a body tag and you can have a class there.
you can also add a script tag with the function that changes the body class like this 

then all you have to do is attach the click event to the buttons

<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeClass(className){
document.body.className = className; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body class="myColor">
<button onclick="changeClass('blue')">Blue</button>
<button  onclick="changeClass('black')">Black</button>
<button  onclick="changeClass('red')">Red</button>
</body>

Comment: @OhadMilchgrub - I didn't know about not using a class on the <html> tag. What I am doing is using it to change the css theme. Is there a performance problem or something with using a class on <html> ?

Comment: it's not a performance issue (the script here is very basic anyway). but it's just a bad practice. the HTML tag denotes the entire page, whereas the body tag is the root tag of all that is displayed in the page, so as a rule classes shouldn't be applied to the html tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add name attribute to the button and make it your css classname.

Single line:

```
<button name="className1" 
        onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className=this.name;"
        >Blue</button>

//other buttons
```

With a function:

```
function changeColour(cName){
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    elem.className = cName;
}

<button name="className1" onclick="changeColour(this.name)">Blue</button>
<button name="className2" onclick="changeColour(this.name)">Black</button>
<button name="className3" onclick="changeColour(this.name)">Red</button>
```

Or alternatively, you can use:

```
var elem = document.documentElement;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your solutions work very nicely. I will accept this answer. I am also wondering how I can use local storage to store the last choice. I will make this into another question and post that now. Thanks.

Comment: Why not `document.documentElement` instead of that complicated `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]`?

Comment: @Pavlo: Sure, that would be another alternative for `html tag element` but getElementsByTagName() is more generic for any element.

Comment: @Pavlo: - So do you mean to use document.documentElement('html') ?

Comment: @Anne: it is a property which returns the document's documentElement.

Comment: @Kaf: - My css uses html.black p { etc.  So if I use this then will it be the same as document.documentElement('html') ?  Thanks

Comment: It is `not a method`, so you cannot pass `html` tagName as a parameter to it. it is a `property` to return the `html element`. I would recommend you to use the function approach as it is more clean and neat and easy to maintain..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var elem = document.querySelector("html");
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('button'), function(el) {
   el.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
});
function changeColor(event) {
    //console.log( this.innerHTML);
    if( this.innerHTML === 'Blue' ) {
        elem.setAttribute( "class", "blueClass" );
    }
    else if( this.innerHTML === 'Red' ) {
        elem.setAttribute( "class", "redClass" );
    }
    //Some things

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    if(theme){
       document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className = theme ;
    }
}
    function setClass(){
        var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className = this.name;
        localStorage.setItem("theme",this.name);
    };
```

Even you better use querySelector rather getElementsBytagName.

**html**

```
<button name="dark" onclick="setClass()">Dark</button>
<button name="light" onclick="setClass()">Light</button>
```